# How to set global environment variables in Linux Mint 18 “Sarah” Xfce?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

I’m using Linux Mint 18 “Sarah” Xfce and I have installed Java using [this guide](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372). It works, but I don’t know how to set `JAVA_HOME` variable for all my users.

How to set global environment variables for all users in Linux Mint?

Comment: also asked in linuxmint forums, wating for help:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=238371&p=1270381#p1270381 

At the moment I solved for some users defining JAVA_HOME in .bash_aliases but i desire a global solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I set global environment variables in Linux Mint?

Set them in `/etc/profile`.

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>
> After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Source [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Lelanthran Really? Care to explain why you think it doesn't?

Comment: That sets the environment only for the shell, specifically for sh-compatible shells. When OP launches his program from the menu or the panel or the desktop launcher it wont' get any of the variables set in /etc/profile. OP specifically asked for setting an environment veriable *GLOBALLY* i.e. it must be set even when not running a terminal, or a shell, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Set your environment variable in `/etc/environment`, if you want it to be available for all users, even when they don't start a shell, just log in to a desktop environment.